# Get Offline messages in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, offline

In my chat application I want to get the offline messages when the user signs in ( if anybody has sent him messages) . I am getting the notifications when the user is in online state and not able to get the messages after the user signs in back. I have checked the xmpp log cat also. I am able to read the offline messages there but i am unable to notify the user his/her ofline mesages.

Here is the listener which I am using in onStart of my service ( service is immediately started on user logon)

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        final PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //notification(packet.getFrom());
                packet = collector.nextResult();
                Message message = (Message)packet;
                senderName = packet.getFrom();

                int alphaPOS = senderName.indexOf("@");
                String subSenderName = senderName.substring(0,alphaPOS); 


                if(UserChatActivity.checkPresence==false){

                    notificationforChat(subSenderName+": "+message.getBody(),packet.getFrom().toString());

               }

            }

        }, filter);

    }
```

This works fine when user is online. But I want that once the user logs in he should be notified his messages

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that your XMPP server supports [XEP 0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html), the message archiving extension of XMPP.

That same extension will explain how you can retrieve the archived messages.

For [ejabberd](http://ejabberd.im), you can install and configure [the mod_archive extension](http://www.ejabberd.im/mod_archive) for this. It will save the messages to a SQL backend.

Comment: Thanks for the helo @JC Brand. Can't the above be a soln ? Many programmers has achieved following the above one. Log cat shows the offline messages also. I have seen myself.
Thanks

Comment: If you merely want the messages sent to your user while he/she was offline, then I think it largely depends on your XMPP server. I use ejabberd and it will send the offline messages immediately once the user logs in.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. Ok your means is your good but i think its d other way around. Can we do it in any other way something like above or offline message manager type ?

Comment: @JCBrand u got any solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

Change the filter to filter messages of type Message.class not chat messages because offline messages are not of type chat (I don't think)

```
PacketFilter filter = new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class);
```

See how you go.

Actually re reading your question; are you saying that you can see the offline message being received in LogCat but not on the screen? Where are you logging the messages being received?